# IntelliJ Auto build with errors but not errors in editor

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm Using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2 to work on a Java w/gradle project.

When I try to run a JUnit test the Autobuild is triggered and it complains with the following message:

> Auto build completed with errors

In the Problems tab I see over 100 erros and when I click on them to investigate I can see that these are not real errors, the editor has no red squiggly anywhere and if I look into specific errors (like java: cannot find symbol) I confirm they are invalid errors.

I've tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart" and "Rebuild Project" with no luck

Comment: Have you configured a project SDK?

Comment: Yes, and I have to add, this error is sudden, everything was working perfectly and after some branch switching and merging (using git) I started getting all these issues. It's not the first time this happens, yesterday it resolved itself magically.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you managed to solve it somehow? I am facing the same issue and it seems it affected the LiveReload function.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many things, but I think the issue got resolved when I switched the Gradle "Build and run using" setting from Gradle to IntelliJ.
[image: gradle settings]